# Objective-C prints special character different than NodeJS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js

[image]

Objective-C`NSLog(@"\xc2\xbfhello")` and javascript `console.log("\xc2\xbfhello")` has a different result,why?

Comment: Please post both the code and the output as text in your question, not as pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `\x` hexadecimal escape sequence in Javascript has a fixed length of **two** digits that does **not** use the UTF-8 encoding.
So to get the `¿` you only need `0xBF`:

```
console.log('\xbfhello');
```

or `String.fromCharCode(0x00bf)` or `String.fromCharCode(0x000000bf)`

The `\x` in `NSLog` **uses** the UTF-8 encoding.

So if you were trying to output `Â¿hello` it would be:

```
NSLog(@"\xc3\x82\xc2\xbfhello");
```

or just the `¿hello` you could use the Unicode escape sequence which would be the same in both:

```
NSLog(@"\u00bfhello");
```

and

```
console.log('\u00bfhello');
```

More info here:

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bf/index.htm

Here for Unicode in Javascript:

https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/

Here for Unicode in Objective-C:

https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/